# tkinter Canvas changing frames and function params

Tags: python, function, tkinter, parameters

I am currently working on a tkinter project in which I am changing frames using the Canvas widget. so far I have this:

```
class StartPage(Frame):
#defines what is supposed to be running when the class is called
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)#parent class = USBSecure
        Frame.configure(self, background = 'dark grey')

        self.frames = {}

        #creates button to get to the help page
        helppage = Canvas(self, width = 200, height = 50, background = mycolor)#,  font = "Helvetica 16 bold italic", fg = 'silver')
        helppage.create_text(100, (50/2), text = 'Help',font = "Helvetica 16 ")





        #creates endProgram button
        endPrgm = Canvas(self, width = 200, height = 50, background = mycolor)#,  font = "Helvetica 16 bold italic", fg = 'silver')
        endPrgm.create_text(100, (50/2), text = 'End the Program',font = "Helvetica 16 ")

        #binds the buttons
        helppage.bind('<Button-1>', self.screenChanger)
        endPrgm.bind('<Button-1>', USBSecure.endProgram)

        #grids the buttons
        helppage.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky='nsew')
        endPrgm.grid(row=1, column = 0, sticky="nsew")


    #help screen
    def screenChanger(self, event):
        for screen in (HelpPage,LogfilePage):
            frame = screen(container, self)        
            self.frames[screen] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky="nsew")

        frame = self.frames[HelpPage]
        frame.tkraise()
```

The code above works perfectly, but...

I am trying to make the screen changer function take in another variable, such as `pageNum`, like this:

```
#help screen
def screenChanger(self, event, pageNum):
    for screen in (HelpPage,LogfilePage):
        frame = screen(container, self)        
        self.frames[screen] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky="nsew")
    if pageNum == 1:
        frame = self.frames[HelpPage]
        frame.tkraise()
```

then I pass the `pageNum` like this:

```
    helppage.bind('<Button-1>', self.screenChanger(1))
```

However, when I do this, I get an error that looks like

```
TypeError: screenChanger() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pageNum'
>>>
```

I have tried `helppage.bind('<Button-1>', self.screenChanger(pageNum=1))`, but that gives me a similar error of

```
TypeError: screenChanger() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'
>>>
```

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

EDIT:

So I have taken into account the changes that Vikas Damodar said, so now I have this.

```
    #binds the buttons
    helppage.bind('<Button-1>', self.screenChanger(Page = HelpPage))
    logfile.bind('<Button-1>', self.screenChanger(Page = LogfilePage))
    endPrgm.bind('<Button-1>', USBSecure.endProgram)

    #grids the buttons
    helppage.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky='nsew')
    logfile.grid(row=1, column = 0, sticky='nsew')
    endPrgm.grid(row=2, column = 0, sticky="nsew")


#help screen
def screenChanger(Page, self, event=None):
    frame = Page(container, self)        
    self.frames[Page] = frame
    frame.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky="nsew")

    frame = self.frames[Page]
    frame.tkraise()
```

However, I am now getting this error:

```
TypeError: screenChanger() got multiple values for argument 'Page'
```

Comment: `def screenChanger(self, event=None, pageNum):` try like this, Actually why you add argument `event` here ?I couldn't see you used that one in your method.

Comment: `helppage.bind('<Button-1>', self.screenChanger(1))` does not do what you think it does. It will call `self.screenChanger(1)` immediately, and bind `None` to the event.

Answer (score 0):

In your method `screenChanger` you have given 2 arguments. `event` and `pageNum`, So when you call the function you have to pass both parameters, else you can give some default value.
 From your question i think you only want to pass `pageNum`.The `event` I couldn't see you used anywhere.So you can try like this, It will give default value for event.

```
def screenChanger(self, event=None, pageNum):
    for screen in (HelpPage,LogfilePage):
       frame = screen(container, self) 
.....
```

Then you can call
your method like `self.screenChanger(pageNum=1)`

Comment: OK, so I did that and now i get a syntax error that says "non-default argument follows default argument". what do i do with that?

Comment: also, setting event to none runs the program not when the canvas is clicked but when the program begins